# Coldfusion Server Standalone server displaying source code

Tags: coldfusion, webserver

I needed to install Coldfusion 8 on my local Windows 7 PC, to do some testing. I took the easy route and installed the Standalone server, which included a built in web server. I didn't really need a fully fledged web server, just needed to test.

So after some time of Coldfusion working fine. It started displaying the source code of the page. In other words, Coldfusion was not parsing the page. Merely displaying the source code.

I've worked out that the following line will make the page display source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Even if I remove this line from the source code, the source code is still displayed. So I have to make another .cfm file with all the code except the above line, for it to run.

My question is, how do I clear the Coldfusion Standalone Web Server's cache? I've tried the usual restarting of Coldfusion to no avail.

**Update**: I eventually used a workaround of just renaming the files ie: testing1.cfm, testing2.cfm. For anyone else getting this issue, just use a standalone web server like Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting ColdFusion?

Have you tried clearing the cache in your browser?

For what it is worth, I prefer to use a web server even when doing development. I have found that using the CF web server and having all my projects under the CF web root can lead to pathing issues in production.

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache and using a different browser, just in case. I would also normally use a separate web server, but I really needed it on a very temporary basis.

Comment: In the time you spent trying to resolve this issue you could have installed Apache and moved along. :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already fixed this issue but there is an option in the ColdFusion administrator under the Settings > Caching option.  At the bottom is a button named *Clear Template Cache Now*.  Clicking that button will empty (remove) any templates that ColdFusion has cached.  The next request to that template will force ColdFusion to recompile it if it has been modified.

Comment: I tried that originally, but it seems that the issue lies with the web server (JRun to my knowledge). So clearing the Coldfusion cache does nothing.